# UCMA recording phone conversations

Tags: lync, ucma

I have been asked by my manager to carry out some research to see whether it would be possible to write an application using the UCMA 4.0 SDK which would be able to record phone conversations on our network.

I've been looking through the examples the SDK provides, and have managed to write a console app which sits on my machine waiting for incoming calls, once a call comes in it then saves a recording to a local folder.

This is all well and good, but I need something which would sit on the server and pick up all calls coming in for all users (or specific users, anything really).

My question then, is something like this possible? And if so, can anyone point me in the right direction?

We are running Lync Server 2013 on a Windows server 2012 box.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MSPL script to reroute incoming calls to your UCMA application:

[Rerouting Requests to a UCMA Application with MSPL](http://blog.greenl.ee/2011/09/04/rerouting-requests-ucma-application-mspl/)